# How to read each line in an input text file and determine if each line is true or false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the goal was to make a boolean (true and false)expression evaluator. The way I went at it was to get all the true expressions from the book I am using and make them into a list. Then from the input file i just took the first line and used "if lines in strings:" to give me if the input exactly matched one of the strings in the list. But I want to make it read each line of the text file and tell me if each line is true or false and don't know how to make that work, I got it to read the first line and tell me if it is true/false but I dont know how to do it for multiple lines.

Here is my code so far:

```
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
#List expressions that are true
strings = ['T', '( ~ F )','T & T', 'T | T', 'T | F', 'F | T', '~ ( T & F )',
        '~ ( F & T )', '~ ( F & F )', '( T | F ) & ~ ( T & F )' , '( F | T ) & ~ ( F & T )',
       '( T & T ) | ( ~ T )', '( T & T ) | ( ~ F )', '( T & F ) | ( ~ F )', '( F & T ) | ( ~ F )',
       '( F & F ) | ( ~ F )', '~ ( ~ T )', '( ~ F ) & ( ~ F )', '( ~ T ) | ( ~ F )', '( ~ F ) | ( ~ T )',
       '( ~ F ) | ( ~ F )', 'T | ( ~ T )']
#read input// only use the first line// if line == strings then return true if not return false
lines = input_file.readline()
lines = input_file.readline()


def readline(line):
    if lines in strings:
                    return True
    else:
                    return False

if readline(lines) == True:
    output_file.write('True')
    print('Check output.txt.')
else:
    output_file.write('False')
##                          'The expression in BooleanExpression.txt is FALSE or the following:\n'
##                          'You typed it in wrong, or expression was not     defined in the\n'
##                          '"Discrete Mathematics with Applications" book.')
    print('Check output.txt.')
#close files        

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

So if my input.txt looks like this:

```
( ~ F )
( ~ T )
T | T
```

The output.txt should look like this:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code here instead of pastebin, it's short enought and way better for readability.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please ***DO NOT*** post your code on external websites.

Comment: Could you please post your code, and what you have tried so far in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for putting it in pastebin and not formatting it right. Should be looking better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since idk how to format things in comments if thats a thing, heres what i have now.  @achampion

```
def readline(lines):
    if lines in strings:
        return True
    else:
        return False

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as output_file:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
        for lines in input_file:
            if readline(lines) == True:
                output_file.write('True\n')
                print('true')
            else:
                output_file.write('False\n')
                print('false')
```

Comment: It looks ok, I've updated it a little, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Well a bit late on this, but the only issue came from the strings that i used other than that everything worked fine. In the text file you would use enter to make a new line which I didn't take account of. So I made a duplicate of the strings with \n right after it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put the `readline` inside a loop. However file type objects support iteration so you could just use:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if readline(line) == True:
            ...
```

However, you might want to consider actually parsing the text and evaluating it so you could handle any boolean expression.

Comment: So it loops now using the sample code that you wrote, but it gives false when doing more than 1 line. I tested one line and it gave me the correct answer, but when I use more than 1 it gives false for everything. Any more ideas while I continue overlooking if anything doesnt seem right?

Comment: @jesseym without seeing your code hard to tell what is going wrong

Comment: posted it as an answer cause im new to posting and idk how to format things in comments.